# Entity framework with HBase

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, hbase

Hi I want to create Entity framework code first for HBase Database . most examples write code to create tables no the concept of code first to handle upgrade schema and so on

Comment: Did you see [this link](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/hbase-ado-codefirst.rst)?

Comment: @anderson this won't require to buy a license right

Comment: Sorry. Didin't pay attention it was trial software.